# Can we measure the current created by single electron in spacetime?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements

Consider single hydrogen atom in the ground state. Does there exist an experimental procedure that would determine the 0th component of the current $J_\mu(x) = \bar{\psi}(x)\gamma_\mu \psi(x)$ created by the electron as a function of spacetime point?

Comment: If you want to see anything about the distribution of constituent particles with some spatial resolution your best bet is probably deep inelastic scattering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_inelastic_scattering (only not for hadrons in this case!)